# Simulationg row-level locking transaction

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, transactions

I have implemented row-level locking transaction for multiple users reading and writing the same row using the following logic.

```
if(isset($_POST['button']){
    if($condition == true){
        mysqli_autocommit($mysqli, FALSE);
        mysqli_begin_transaction($mysqli, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);
        //...Update table here
        mysqli_commit($mysqli);//commit records to database and
    }else{
        mysqli_rollback($mysqli);
    }
}
```

If i check tables in the database after clicking a button the results are as i expect,the only problem is that I am not sure if there is any way i can simulate multiple users to test if deadlocks will likely to occur.Is there a better approach to this.Also Xammp is throwing me the following error

> Warning: mysqli_begin_transaction(): This server version doesn't support 'READ WRITE' and 'READ ONLY'. Minimum 5.6.5 is required in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\somepage.php on line 38

Comment: What version of MYSQL are you running? Error is reported in **line 38** but you have shown **only 10 lines**

Comment: That wont deadlock anyway. the second execution will block and wait for the first script to commit, then the second execution will continue, upidate and commit its change

Comment: @RiggsFolly ther is a bunch of SELECT and Update statements in the area I commented `//...update table here` the line `mysqli_begin_transaction ()` is the one causing the error in the complete code it's on line 38.But it's working anyway. I will test on a live server maybe the version for my hosting company is up to date.I will also check with them before I create an account.I was trying to simplify my post.Sorry for confusion.I will edit it.